# How to pass a flag to klog for structured logging

Tags: kubernetes, logging, azure-aks

As part of kubernetes 1.19, [structured logging](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/09/04/kubernetes-1-19-introducing-structured-logs/) has been implemented.

I've [read](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/system-logs/) that kubernetes log's engine is `klog` and structured logs are following this format :

```
<klog header> "<message>" <key1>="<value1>" <key2>="<value2>" ...
```

Cool ! But even better, you apparently can pass a `--logging-format=json` flag to `klog` so logs are generated in `json` directly !

```
{
   "ts": 1580306777.04728,
   "v": 4,
   "msg": "Pod status updated",
   "pod":{
      "name": "nginx-1",
      "namespace": "default"
   },
   "status": "ready"
}
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find out how and where I should specify that `--logging-format=json` flag.

Is it a `kubectl` command? I'm using Azure's aks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--logging-format=json` is a flag which need to be set on all Kuberentes System Components ( Kubelet, API-Server, Controller-Manager & Scheduler). You can check all flags [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/).

Unfortunately you cant do it right now with AKS as you have the managed control plane from Microsoft.

Comment: Ok, that was I thought. Thanks !